# Erlang: Supervisor start_child succeeds but no child is added

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, gen-server, erlang-supervisor

I'm working on building a supervisor in Erlang that looks like this:

```
-module(a_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

%% API
-export([start_link/0, init/1]).

start_link() ->
  {ok, supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [])}.

init(_Args) ->
  RestartStrategy = {simple_one_for_one, 5, 3600},
  ChildSpec = {
    a_gen_server,
    {a_gen_server, start_link, []},
    permanent,
    brutal_kill,
    worker,
    [a_gen_server]
  },
  {ok, {RestartStrategy,[ChildSpec]}}.
```

And this is how my gen_server looks:

```
-module(a_gen_server).
-behavior(gen_server).

%% API
-export([start_link/2, init/1]).

start_link(Name, {X, Y}) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, Name}, ?MODULE, [Name, {X,Y}], []),
  ok.

init([Name, {X,Y}]) ->
  process_flag(trap_exit, true),
  io:format("~p: position {~p,~p}~n",[Name, X, Y]),
  {ok, {X,Y}}.
```

My gen_server works completely fine. When I run the supervisor as:

```
1> c(a_sup).
{ok,a_sup}
2> Pid = a_sup:start_link().
{ok,{ok,<0.85.0>}}
3> supervisor:start_child(a_sup, [Hello, {4,3}]).
Hello: position {4,3}
{error,ok}
```

I couldn't understand where the `{error, ok}` is coming from, and if there is an error, then what is causing it. So this is what I get when I check the status of the children:

```
> supervisor:count_children(a_sup).
[{specs,1},{active,0},{supervisors,0},{workers,0}]
```

This means that there are no children registered with the supervisor yet despite it calling the init method of the gen_server and spawning a process? Clearly there is some error preventing the method to complete successfully but I can't seem to gather any hints to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `a_gen_server:start_link` (since that's the function used to in the child spec) is expected to return `{ok, Pid}`, not just `ok`.

As [the docs](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#Child%20specification) put it:

> The start function must create and link to the child process, and must
> return `{ok,Child}` or `{ok,Child,Info}`, where `Child` is the pid of the
> child process and `Info` any term that is ignored by the supervisor.
>
> The start function can also return `ignore` if the child process for
> some reason cannot be started, in which case the child specification
> is kept by the supervisor (unless it is a temporary child) but the
> non-existing child process is ignored.
>
> If something goes wrong, the function can also return an error tuple
> `{error,Error}`.

Comment: Thank you! Changing the method to `start_link(Name, {X, Y}) ->
  gen_server:start_link({local, Name}, ?MODULE, [Name, {X,Y}], []).` fixes the error :)